# How modify the result default date format to this(dd-month-year) format in DatePicker control?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I am using datepicker control as a modal. By this i can able to get result date in default format. I want to display and store that in dd-mm-yy format.
 In this case how shall i achieve?

```js
//Modalview function

 createdpModelView(args) {
        let that = this;
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let options: ModalDialogOptions = {
            context: currentDate.toDateString(),
            fullscreen: false,
            viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef
        };
        this.modalService.showModal(Datepicmodal, options)
            .then((dateresult: Date) => {
                console.log("date result " + dateresult);
           
------------------------------------------------------------------
//here i am facing issue//
                if (args === "issue") {
let datePicker = this.page.getViewById<DatePicker>("datePicker");
let selectedDate = new Date(datePicker.year, datePicker.month - 1, datePicker.day);
this.issuedateng = selectedDate;
console.log("selected date " + selectedDate);
                } 
------------------------------------------------------------------

else if (args === "expiry") {
                    this.expirydateng = dateresult;
                 
                } 
            });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do.

```
  <Button #dobFdwomponentPersonalInfo id="dobFdwomponentPersonalInfo" [text]="fdwPersonalInfo?.dob | date: 'dd - MMM - yyyy'" (tap)="openSelectDateModalScreen('dob')"></Button>
```

Hope this help